# How to format numbers with no grouping separator

Tags: java

I'm trying to format a BigDecimal value by using methods of DecimalFormat.format().

My problem, is I don't know how to set DecimalFormats DecimalFormatSymbol to format text without any grouping separators.

I'd like to know how to set a grouping symbol and use the format methods. I know how to do it differently by using replace or others methods but it's not what I want.

So I need to know how to set an empty character as grouping operator.

Example:

```
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat();
DecimalFormatSymbols decFS = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
decFS.setGroupingSeparator( '\0' );
dec.setDecimalFormatSymbols( decFS );
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(1000);
String result = dec.format(number);
```

I want to get "1000" as string with no other characters. Please help

note(react to post): I want to formate the number only, without grouping.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Simply:

```
 DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat();     
 dec.setGroupingUsed(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want any formatting marks in the number you should just call toString on the BigDecimal Object.

```
import java.math.*;

public class TestBigDecimal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(1000);
        String result = number.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String result = String.valueOf(number);
```

returns your number as a string with no formatting.